# Do mutations that cause the loss of a complex trait occur more often than mutations causing gain of a complex traits?

Tags: evolution, population-genetics, mutations, human-evolution, molecular-evolution

The [Wiki entry on the evolution of biological complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_biological_complexity#Selection_for_simplicity_and_complexity) states that "[m]utations causing loss of a complex trait occur more often than mutations causing gain of a complex trait". There is no inline  citation supporting this claim, nor could I find anything of the sort in the bibliography. So I was wondering whether this is thought to be the case and what key work has been done concerning this claim i.e. major papers either for or against the thesis.

Comment: Many mutations are needed for complex gain of function. Only a tiny mutation is needed for loss. Only one change is needed to break a long chain of synthesis. For example, the chain needed for melanin sythesis - see albinism http://www.albinism.org/information-bulletin-what-is-albinism/

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler While the principle you mention is a good general guide, there are exceptions. For example, a single mutation in a regulatory region can change the location and/or timing of expression of a protein and produce complex changes. See the often dramatic results of mutations in insect Hox genes.

Answer (score 4):

While I don't have a citation at hand, I don't think that one is needed. The principle follows directly from the notion of mutation in a complex system.  Put simply, once you've got a functional complex trait in play, there are many ways to break it and much fewer that can further improve it.

This fact is often mis-interpreted by creationists to claim the evolution of complex traits is impossible. With a population under selective pressure, it doesn't matter if more mutations are negative than positive, because the positive traits produce many more descendants.

To take a current example, the SARS-CoV-2 virus has an important complex trait in the form of the spike protein that enables it to invade human cells. An infected person produces a vast number of copies of the virus, many of which have mutations that destroy the functionality of the spike protein. So those mutations disappear immediately, while the non-mutated or neutrally-mutated copies infect as usual and the rare improvement in efficacy brings us developments like the Delta strain.

Comment: +1 I think it is worth qualifying what is meant by *more often*. In a particular individual the loss of trait is certainly more likely than the gain. On the other hand, the direction of evolution as a whole demonstrates acquisition rather than the loss of traits: complex organisms evolved from simple ones, contrary to the creationist argument.

Comment: @RogerVadim "Direction of evolution" and "creationist argument" should have some scientific definitions attached if they're to be posted here, I think. This question seem to be simply about the mutation event (based on the context of the referenced wiki quote).

Comment: @Armand I am saying that "*more often*" is both correct and wrong, depending on what one is talking about.